# Improving rendering performance with Jbuilder and Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, performance, rendering

The app I'm working on responds to most requests with JSON objects or collections thereof. We're using [Jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) to construct those responses. The amount of data rendered is fairly large (several thousand objects in various nested structures - once formatted and fully expanded, there are as many as 10,000 lines of JSON for a typical response). This rendering is taking a significant amount of time - about 1/3 of the total request time, according to NewRelic.

I'm looking for some kind of guide, set of tips, or other resource that will help me make sure I'm getting the best possible performance out of JBuilder. I'm also curious if there are performance comparisons available for Jbuilder vs. [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) or other similar tools.

Edit: I've found a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/issues/45) that complains about Jbuilder performance, but the only actual suggestion anyone's made is 'don't use Jbuilder'. Well, actually, they used slightly stronger language, but there's still no word on *why* Jbuilder is so slow, what, if anything, can be done to get around it, or how other tools for the same task compare.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

jbuilder builds up a big hash containing your data and then uses `ActiveSupport::JSON` to turn it into json. There are faster json emitters as the following micro benchmark shows (make sure you have the multijson and yajl-ruby gems installed)

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'active_support'
require 'multi_json'
sample = {menu: {
    header: "SVG Viewer",
    items: [
        {id: "Open"},
        {id: "OpenNew", label: "Open New"},
        nil,
        {id: "ZoomIn", label: "Zoom In"},
        {id: "ZoomOut", label: "Zoom Out"},
        {id: "OriginalView", label: "Original View"},
        nil,
        {id: "Quality"},
        {id: "Pause"},
        {id: "Mute"},
        nil,
        {id: "Find", label: "Find..."},
        {id: "FindAgain", label: "Find Again"},
        {id: "Copy"},
        {id: "CopyAgain", label: "Copy Again"},
        {id: "CopySVG", label: "Copy SVG"},
        {id: "ViewSVG", label: "View SVG"},
        {id: "ViewSource", label: "View Source"},
        {id: "SaveAs", label: "Save As"},
        nil,
        {id: "Help"},
        {id: "About", label: "About Adobe CVG Viewer..."}
    ]
}}


MultiJson.engine = :yajl
Benchmark.bmbm(5) do |x|
  x.report 'activesupport' do
    1000.times {ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(sample)}
  end
  x.report 'yajl' do
    1000.times {MultiJson.encode(sample)}
  end
end
```

On my machine this produces

```
                    user     system      total        real
activesupport   1.050000   0.010000   1.060000 (  1.068426)
yajl            0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.021169)
```

ie to encode the sample object 1000 times active support took a hair over 1 second, MultiJson (using the yajl engine) took 21ms.

JBuilder is hardcoded to use ActiveSupport::JSON, but MultiJSON (a gem that lets you switch between json libraries) is a trivial drop in and is already a dependency of ActiveSupport - see my [fork of jbuilder](https://github.com/fcheung/jbuilder/). I've opened a pull request, but until then you could try using this fork (or create your own - it's a one line change)

Comment: Switching to MultiJson seems to cut about 60ms off of the 400ms or so that we spend doing rendering for a typical request. Not the huge change I was hoping for, but for a one-line change, not bad at all. Thanks.

Comment: @Frederick: I see the one line of change from the link:- https://github.com/fcheung/jbuilder/commit/a58b355f68bc39b1fddf8b178f3844c5d4f65501 merged with rails master, so I am guessing we don't need to make any changes. Can you please confirm if my inference is correct.

Comment: Yes - the pull request was merged - not sure what version it ended up in

Comment: @FrederickCheung as per the Jbuilder Railscast(http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder), it is said that its added as a separate gem so that it can be used across multiple Rails versions.

Comment: I just switched to  yajl-ruby and I got a tremendous performance boost when it comes to rendering an array of 800 records in a jbuilder view

Answer (score 4):

Consider switching to Rabl and adding some [caching](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/wiki/Caching-in-RABL). Given you have thousands of objects in nested structures, some nodes of your resulting JSON can be rendered as partials and cached - the performance gain can be huge.

Apart from this Rabl performance is slightly better than performance of JBuilder, but I find Rabl syntax sometimes confusing and I'd switch to JBuilder once it has fragment caching implemented.

Answer (score 0):

As stated before [JBuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) builds a hash, then serializes that hash to JSON.

The same with caching, there is the main hash and the cached hash get merged into the main hash which still needs to be converted to JSON.

My solution was [TurboStreamer](https://github.com/malomalo/turbostreamer). TurboStreamer outputs directly to an IO/Stream/String therefore skipping the serialization step that JBuilder (and at first glance this still applies to [Rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl), and to_json depending on usage).

For us this has significantly reduced render time & GC times (due to building the hash in jbuilder) and allows us to start streaming JSON out to the client as we get our results. The downside is TurboStreamer is a little more verbose and explicit.

Performance Test A (no caching involved):

- [source](https://gist.github.com/rolftimmermans/3638182)
- [results](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1018543/33420617-3e3f59b6-d5ea-11e7-991e-68a87d237aa4.png)

Performance Test B (mostly all caching):

- [source](https://gist.github.com/dirk/4048df31641f5dab1c67)
- [results](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1018543/33420610-38f10068-d5ea-11e7-80fe-971180272fec.png)